# How to convert RGB to Wavelength in python

Tags: python, colors

I am trying to extract the **wavelength** of a pixel by mapping its **R,G,B** values ​​(0 to 255) with the individual bandwidths of their visible [wavelengths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bNF2.png)

**Here is my current python program**

```
#variable

r, g, b = 245, 122, 155 #let's take RGB value of a pixel



def my_map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):  #Prominent map function
            return int((x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min)


# Map 8 bits value of R,G,B (0 to 255) to their bandwidth of wavelength
        
R = my_map(r, 0, 255, 499, 700)# rgb 0 = 499 nm, rgb 255 = 700   
G = my_map(g, 0, 255, 440 , 580) # rgb 0 = 440 nm, rgb 255 = 580
B = my_map(b, 0, 255, 380, 490)   # rgb 0 = 440 nm, rgb 255 = 490

print('\nWavelength of R', r , 'is', R, '\nWavelength of G', g , 'is', G, '\nWavelength of B', b , 'is', B,)



#mean of constituent wavelengths

Wavelength = R+G+B
Wavelength /= 3
print('\nWavelength : ', Wavelength )
```

The map function is working fine, the individual **wavelength** value of r or g or b is **accurate**, but the wavelength is a point value in the entire visible spectrum, etc.

In above code I take average of RGB, but it is not accurate. I know this is not the way.

**What should I do for accurate wavelength measurement** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481345/convert-rgb-pixel-to-wavelength

Comment: Do you realize that most combinations of red and blue, such as magenta, don't have a wavelength?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing guarantees that the RGB values you picked are on the spectral locus, thus you need to find the [dominant wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominant_wavelength).

You need to know which RGB colourspace your RGB values are encoded with, convert to CIE XYZ tristimulus values then CIE xy chromaticity coordinates and finally, you can compute the dominant wavelength. In your case, and because your RGB values are integers, you need to also normalise them to floating point representation whilst not forgetting to apply the inverse encoding colour component transfer function.

Using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour), which I maintain,  and assuming that the values are encoded with **sRGB** here is how you could do it:

```py
import colour
import numpy as np

RGB_f = np.array([245.0, 122.0, 155.0]) / 255

# Using the individual definitions:
RGB_l = colour.models.eotf_sRGB(RGB_f)
XYZ = colour.RGB_to_XYZ(
    RGB_l,
    colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_sRGB.whitepoint,
    colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_sRGB.whitepoint,
    colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_sRGB.matrix_RGB_to_XYZ,
)
xy = colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ)
wl, xy_1, xy_2 = colour.dominant_wavelength(
    xy, colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_sRGB.whitepoint
)

# Using the automatic colour conversion graph:
wl, xy_1, xy_2 = colour.convert(RGB_f, "Output-Referred RGB", "Dominant Wavelength")

print(wl, xy_1, xy_2)

colour.plotting.colour_style()
figure, axes = colour.plotting.plot_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
    diagram_opacity=0.15, standalone=False
)

xy_i = np.vstack([xy_1, xy, colour.models.RGB_COLOURSPACE_sRGB.whitepoint, xy_2])
axes.plot(xy_i[..., 0], xy_i[..., 1], "-o")
colour.plotting.render()
```

> -496.0 [ 0.63564364  0.21924977] [ 0.0211551   0.42807958]

So here, you will notice that the *dominant wavelength* is negative because the closest intersection is on the line of purples, thus the *complementary wavelength* is returned instead.

[image: Dominant Wavelength]

Answer (score 0):

An answer not requiring any library, useful for teaching purposes since colour library isn't that commonly installed. It is dirty, but I believe simple, robust and convincing.

The colormap was extracted with another script, from [an encyclopaedic source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_visible#/media/Fichier:Visible-spectrum-400-700-nm.png).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colormap = [[6, 1, 31],[12, 0, 40],[14, 0, 51], [16, 1, 60],
 [17, 1, 76], [23, 0, 90], [26, 1, 105], [28, 0, 119], [28, 0, 136], 
[34, 0, 151],[36, 1, 165], [37, 0, 176], [37, 1, 187], [36, 0, 194],
[37, 0, 202], [34, 0, 209], [31, 0, 217], [28, 1, 220], [25, 0, 224],
[18, 1, 227], [16, 0, 229], [14, 0, 233], [10, 0, 237], [9, 0, 237],
[7, 0, 240], [3, 0, 242], [0, 0, 244], [0, 0, 244], [2, 5, 244], 
[1, 8, 244], [0, 13, 242], [0, 18, 242], [2, 22, 239],
[0, 28, 236], [0, 33, 236], [0, 37, 232], [0, 44, 229], [2, 49, 227],
[0, 55, 220], [0, 60, 218], [0, 66, 214], [1, 73, 209], [0, 77, 205],
[0, 84, 200], [0, 91, 194], [0, 96, 193], [0, 101, 189], [0, 106, 182],
[0, 111, 177], [1, 118, 172], [0, 120, 165], [0, 122, 159], 
[0, 128, 153], [1, 131, 147], [1, 132, 140], [1, 135, 134], 
[0, 140, 131], [0, 145, 126], [0, 148, 124], [0, 152, 122], 
[0, 158, 118], [1, 162, 118], [1, 168, 116], [0, 172, 114],
[0, 178, 113],[0, 182, 112], [0, 186, 111], [1, 188, 109], 
[2, 191, 107], [0, 194, 107], [1, 195, 108], [0, 198, 101], 
[1, 200, 99], [0, 204, 96], [1, 209, 97], [2, 211, 94], [1, 217, 90],
[0, 220, 88], [0, 225, 81], [1, 228, 77], [1, 231, 71], [1, 232, 68], 
[0, 230, 60], [0, 230, 52], [0, 230, 43], [0, 230, 33], [0, 228, 21],
[0, 228, 11], [2, 229, 0], [16, 229, 0], [28, 229, 0], [40, 230, 0], 
[56, 232, 0], [72, 232, 2], [84, 230, 1],
[98, 231, 0],[111, 230, 0],[124, 230, 0], [137, 230, 1], [151, 228, 0],
[162, 227, 0], [173, 229, 0], [186, 227, 0], [198, 224, 1], 
[211, 226, 0], [221, 221, 0], [227, 216, 0], [230, 210, 1], 
[237, 201, 1], [240, 193, 1],[242, 184, 0], [245, 173, 0], 
[248, 165, 1], [250, 155, 0], [251, 145, 0], [252, 136, 1], 
[254, 126, 1], [255, 115, 0], [255, 104, 3], [254, 95, 1], [255, 83, 1],
[255, 72, 2], [255, 61, 0], [253, 49, 0], [255, 39, 2],
[253, 28, 0], [255, 17, 4], [255, 8, 1], [254, 2, 1], [254, 0, 10],
[255, 0, 14], [255, 0, 18], [251, 0, 24], [250, 0, 30], [250, 0, 30], 
[248, 0, 35], [246, 0, 41], [246, 0, 41], [242, 0, 40], [242, 0, 40],
[240, 0, 45], [237, 0, 46], [233, 0, 45], [230, 1, 44], [226, 0, 42], 
[222, 0, 41], [218, 0, 39], [214, 0, 38], [206, 0, 36], [200, 1, 34], 
[195, 0, 32], [189, 0, 30], [185, 0, 31], [177, 0, 28], [169, 0, 26],
[162, 0, 24], [152, 0, 23],[144, 1, 21], [136, 1, 18], [128, 1, 20], 
[121, 0, 19], [111, 0, 16], [104, 0, 14], [96, 0, 12], [88, 1, 10], 
[83, 0, 12], [73, 0, 9], [67, 0, 9], [62, 1, 9], [57, 0, 7], [51, 0, 7],
[46, 0, 5], [42, 0, 4], [39, 0, 5], [33, 1, 4], [30, 0, 4],[25, 0, 3], 
[25, 0, 3], [22, 0, 2],[21, 0, 1], [16, 0, 0], [15, 1, 1], [14, 0, 0], 
[12, 0, 0], [9, 0, 1], [9, 0, 1], [8, 0, 0]]


def wave_to_rgb(wavlgth):
    """Input : a float describing a wavelength in nanometer
    Output : a numpy array giving the rgb values (between 0 and 1) 
    associated with the colour percieved at this wavelength """
    a = np.linspace(400,700,len(colormap))
    colorindex = min(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: abs(a[i]-wavlgth))
    col = colormap[colorindex]
    return np.asarray(col)/255

#With a small example to show that this solution makes very convincing results : 

plt.figure(figsize=(13,5))

wavelgthlist = np.linspace(400,700,len(colormap))


plt.plot(wavelgthlist, [wave_to_rgb(k)[0] for k in wavelgthlist],color = (1,0,0) ,linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(wavelgthlist, [wave_to_rgb(k)[1] for k in wavelgthlist],color = (0,1,0) ,linewidth = 2)
plt.plot(wavelgthlist, [wave_to_rgb(k)[2] for k in wavelgthlist],color = (0,0,1) ,linewidth = 2)



plt.ylabel("Intensity of each pixel")
plt.xlabel("Wavelength (nm)")
plt.title("For each wavelength, pixel combination mimicking the perceived colour")

height = 1.05

for line in range(len(wavelgthlist)):
  plt.plot([wavelgthlist[line],wavelgthlist[line]],[height,height*1.05], color = wave_to_rgb(wavelgthlist[line]), linewidth = 3.8, alpha = 1)


plt.show()
```

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTv1f.jpg)

Comment: Thanks but how do I use this map with RGB values ( like in my code), I have seen your graph it is as simple as it should be and  logical

Comment: I realise I misunderstood your question, sorry! Since the emission spectrum of an LED is broad, I'm not sure how to answer your question. At a pinch, you could simply extract the most emitted wavelength, but you'd lose a lot of information by doing that, and that's what the colleague above has already suggested.

Comment: I realise, however, that your problem may be simpler: perhaps you're looking to build a home-made spectrophotometer that calibrates itself? In which case you can at least be sure that each RGB input value will correspond roughly to a wavelength in the spectrum, by construction. In which case, after normalising the maximum intensity, all you have to do is look for the least distant vector in my colormap to deduce the associated wavelength with a precision of less than one nm.

Comment: okay, i will look into it